# AJAX URL is working on one blade but not on other

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am fetching the data from database using AJAX in laravel. Its working fine. Following is the code of my AJAX:

```
$('#salesmanlist_input').on('change', function() {
                var salesmanlist_input = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'sales/lims_salesman_list',
                    data: {
                        data: salesmanlist_input
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("Data in on change salesman is: " + data);
                        
                    }
                });
            });
```

the route I'm using for it is as follows

```
Route::get('sales/lims_salesman_list', 'SaleController@limsSalesmanList')->name('SalesmanList.view');
```

The problem i'm facing is, its working fine on one blade but not working on other blade. On other file its giving the error as

> jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost/alimran_final/sales/sales/lims_salesman_list?data=usama

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? The given "error" does not look like an error to me, so is there any real error message you are facing?

Comment: i tried to changed the url like `../sales/lims_salesman_list`, `/sales/lims_salesman_list`, `/lims_salesman_list`, but its also not working. Yeah i know the code is fine, but dont know why still its not working.

Comment: I suggest you retry with `/sales/lims_salesman_list` with the leading slash.

Answer (score 0):

The url `url: 'sales/lims_salesman_list',` is static. As it will be added to the current url. You should add the url in blade by using the helper `route`.

```
$('#salesmanlist_input').on('change', function() {
                var salesmanlist_input = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "{{ route('SalesmanList.view') }}",
                    data: {
                        data: salesmanlist_input
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("Data in on change salesman is: " + data);
                        
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer, such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Comment: @SNSharma its going to route but its not getting the data, its returning `[object Object]` instead of actual result.

Comment: Just use `console.log(data)`

Answer (score 0):

the Problem You are Facing is that the Route is static,though when you are at /sales url it will also add another sales
as happened to you

---

```
jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost/alimran_final/sales/sales/lims_salesman_list?data=usama
```

you have 2 solutions:

1. change url in ajax request from
   url: 'sales/lims_salesman_list',  to    url: '/sales/lims_salesman_list',
   slash added to begining
2. change url in ajax to url:"{{ route('SalesmanList.view') }}",

---

However I prefer to use Solution 2 hence its more dynamic whenever you change lines in web routes file it will dynamically change

Also try to clear route's Cache